# Objective-C: correct method for passing

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, scope

How can you pass around a variable amongst methods?

I have a `UITabBarController`.

```
- (void)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController 
        didSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController {
     NSLog(@"my ns string %@", viewController.tabBarItem.title);
}
```

I need the NSString variable set so that I can access it when my table's cells are specified within this event. The idea is that the table contents are dependent upon the tab title.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
         cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

In other languages I am familiar with, I always just pass around variables amongst functions or they are variables within the class. I'm new to Objective-C and I'm not sure how to deal with variable scopes.

I read that it could be done by creating a class which is used solely for variables. Is this the correct way to do it? Advice is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I think objective-c is fighting strongly against the type of code you're trying to make, it's very MVC based, and information spread from the top down more or less, essentially the tab bar controller should be passing the string, (or more generally, the smallest amount of outside info needed) then the view controller should do its own setup based on the info passed in. See setters/getters/accessors for more about how to pass the information.

Answer (score 0):

You can still pass variables around in Objective-C - commonly for a view controller that owns the table, you would pass in that string value to it.

If the string were needed in a more global scope, you could put it in the application delegate as a property to access.

If over time too many things end up in the app delegate, you can group them in a singleton - the app delegate itself is a singleton, but you can make other instances that stick around for the lifetime of the application and make central places to store values commonly used across the application.

Answer (score 0):

Objective-C applications in my experience get a bit of a top-down approach. It's a bit parallel, you have the view hierarchy and the controller hierarchy.

The view hierarchy for iphone starts from window, then goes to the first subview, then subsequent subviews.

The controller analogue for window is the application delegate, which usually creates the first view *controller*. From there, each (fullscreen) view has a controller, and they tend to get created and setup by their parent view controllers.

In your case, it seems like the tabs should have identical views, and they should get some form of pointer to their data from your subclass of the *tab bar controller*.

Answer (score 0):

*Note: The following answer is out of the scope of passing values among methods/view controllers.*

If the view controller of the table is one of the view controllers in the tabbar controller, you can get the *title* of the tab bar by just using the line,

```
NSString *title = self.tabbarItem.title;
```

Answer (score 0):

> The idea is that the table contents are dependent upon the tab title.

You can you the 'tag' property insted of the title. I think you can use:

```
//In some place or your UITabBarController
...
UITabBarItem *item;
...
item.tag = YOUR_DEFINED_VALUE;
...


- (void)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController didSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController {
     switch(tabBarController.tabBar.selectedItem.tag) {
case YOUR_DEFINED_VALUE:
...
self.typeOfCell = CELL_TYPE;
[tableView reloadData];
...
}
}
```

[UITabBarItem](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UITabBarItem_Class/Reference/Reference.html) extends from [UIBarItem](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIBarItem_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/UIBarItem) that has the 'tag' property.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this question was never answered correctly. The answer to your question is, you can declare variables as `@property` and pass values between controllers.

For ex:-

If you want to pass something to `viewController`, declare it as a property in that class as,

```
@property(nonatomic, retain) NSString *someValue;
```

and set it as,

```
- (void)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController didSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController {
     viewController.someValue = someValues;
}
```

You can use this in viewController class as,

```
NSLog(@"value is %@", self.someValue);
```

In your case, you can use `self.tabbarItem.title` directly in your `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method.